# @RepositoryRestController not recognized

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

I have the following controller:

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/testables", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get(){

        return "testin it";

    }

}
```

And it is not picked up by Spring. I get 404 when I hit `/apiroot/testables` address. If I change it to be @RestController and add the api root to request mapping value, then it works. Also, if I change the mapping to point to `"/orders/testables"`, it works as `@RepositoryRestController`. I also have the following controller in the same package which works fine:

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class SendEmailController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/orders/{id}/sendOrderEmailToSupplier")
    public void sendOrderEmailToSupplier(@PathVariable("id") Long id, WebRequest request) throws MessagingException {...
```

Comment: How did you setup [basePath](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_changing_the_base_uri)?

Comment: In `application-default.yml`, `spring: data: rest: basePath: /basepath`

Comment: Very strange. In my test project all works as expected. With 1.5.4 or 1.4.3 Spring Boot.

Comment: version 1.4.0 but nvm I changed the return type to `@ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<?>` and moved the mapping under `/products` which is managed by SDR and it works.

Comment: Ups! So your "/testables" doesn't managed by SDR? This is the reason of the issue. `@RepositoryRestController` deal only with managed resources. If you want to build custom operations underneath basePath, use `@BasePathAwareController`.

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote the answer if it was helpful...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@RepositoryRestController` deal with **basePath** only for resources which it manage. In other cases the path should not contain the "base".

If you want to build custom operations underneath **basePath**, you can use `@BasePathAwareController`.